# How to connect a Form with Controller in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

So, I am trying to submit a form on a List Page(http://example.com:3480/List) which is actually a Search implementation. So far I have done this:

**index.cshtml**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Search","ListController"))
{
    <input id=query type=text name=query />
    <input id=btnsearch type=submit value=Search />
}
```

**ListController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Search(FormCollection collection)
        {
            Response.Write("We are here");
            // Get Post Params Here
            string var1 = collection["query"];
            Response.Write(var1);
            return View();
        }
```

**Global.asax**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Details",
                "Details/{id}/{orderid}",
                new { controller = "Details", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, orderid = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
            );



        }
```

Upon Clicking it goes to `http://example.com:3480/ListController/Search` which seems fine.

Now I guess I need to define route in Global.aspx but not sure. What I want is to show result in same View file instead of creating a new one.

At this moment I am unable to get into `Search` method after POSTing form

Comment: Why are you using Response.Write and where do you create a new View?

Comment: @MikeSW for testing, to check whether I am being sent on correct method or not

Comment: *Right now I am not being sent to method that is POSTING data* - thought I would add this comment as your question is misleading.

Comment: @AntP Sorry. I edited question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are currently just using the default route, the reason you are not reaching the action method is that the "Controller" suffix on your route is implicit - it shouldn't be part of your URL.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Search","List"))
```

Additionally, regarding:

> What I want is to show result in same View file instead of creating a new one.

You can easily return a specific view from any controller action by specifying the name of the view in the call to the `View` method:

```
return View("Index");
```

Comment: Global.asax content added in original question

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Pardon? I did not get

Comment: You need to make the change in my answer (remove "Controller" from the parameter in your `BeginForm` call). The routes you have now are fine.

Comment: I rather changed the Method name from `Search` to `Index` for sake of consistency. This time no 404 but no idea of it either whether it accessed `[httpPost]` based method